# How to append a x86 compiled library to an android project

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, build, static-libraries

I am working on an android game project and i am coding under android studio in java , the game needs a long part of code that i have already wrote in **c/c++** under **windows x86** , i am asking if i can append my old library in android studio and call it with java ? can a library compiled for x86 architecture appended in android application ? or do i need to recompile it for android ? if yes **how shall i do that** ? what is the exact way to solve this problem , and thanks .

Comment: No, you can't do this. Your library was written for a differernt OS and architecture, it won't work on Android. You will have to recompile it using Android NDK.

Comment: yes i am asking about how to do that ! and how to call it later from java (android studio exactelly) , thanks a lot :D

Comment: Android x86, or the regular Android ARM?

Comment: regular Android ARM please :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rebuild the library for Android. For that, you need the Android NDK. The [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html) page has links to much of the documentation you'll need to set this up. If you get stuck, try looking at the [NDK samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk). The [hello-jni](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk/hello-jni) example is particularly useful when you're new to the NDK.

There is new support coming out for C++ development in Android Studio, but right now much of the build system is experimental. If you're interested in using the experimental support, you should refer to the [NDK samples here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) instead.